# parse_str doesn't work when the question mark is present?

Tags: php, string, variables, query-string

why I get error when I pass the string with something like 'form.php?', for instance,

```
parse_str('form.php?category=contacts');
echo $category;
```

I get this,

```
Notice: Undefined variable: category in C:\wamp\www\1hundred_2011_MVC\applications\CMS\category_manage.php on line xx
```

but,

```
parse_str('category=contacts');
echo $category;
```

I get what I want,

```
contacts
```

how can I fix it? I have to pass something like `'xxx.php?category=contacts'` to get `'contacts'` or something in the variable.

thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) only parses the query string, not the entire URL. Try using [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) with the component set to `PHP_URL_QUERY` to extract the query string first, then use `parse_str` on that.

```
$url_query = parse_url('form.php?category=contacts', PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($url_query, $output);
echo $output['category'];
```

Result:

```
contacts
```

[See it at ideone.](http://ideone.com/wOSdI)

Comment: Also use the second parameter to store the params from the query string...you don't want to be overwriting variables as was mentioned in this PHP.net entry [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#96035].

Comment: @Yzmir Ramirez: I've updated my answer to show this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`parse_str` will only accept query strings:

```
$q = 'foo?hello=world';
parse_str($q);
echo ${'foo?hello'}; // outputs 'world'
```

Strip the beginning of the URL first:

```
$q = 'foo?hello=world';
parse_str(substr($q, strpos($q, '?')+1);
echo $hello; // outputs 'world'
```

Consider using `parse_str` second argument to have the data in an array instead, to avoid overwriting local variables.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use urldecode plus return extracted variables like so:

```
... some helper class...
/**
* Return parsed serialized JQuery object as PHP array of extracted variables
*/
protected static function parseFields($encoded){
    parse_str(urldecode($encoded));
    unset($encoded);
    return get_defined_vars();
}
```

Also, you may want to utilize the JQuery function "$.param(data)" for creating URL encoded string:

```
var encoded=$.param(fields);
```

and submit via AJAX/POST request to server to function parseFields().